# Webstorm—Change require syntax to import syntax with a shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, import, ecmascript-6, webstorm

On npmjs.com, libraries often provide code snippets that start like

```
var md5 = require('md5');
```

but this syntax is like a million years old. I usually copy and paste the code and transform it to

```
import md5 from 'md5';
```

ES2016 style. Is there a shortcut in WebStorm / IntelliJ to do this automatically? Or any other way to not having to do this manually?

Comment: no, there is no way to convert 'require' to ES6 imports. if you miss this feature, please create a feature request in youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Thanks lena, why not make it an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### IntelliJ 2016.3 & 2017

Starting from IntelliJ 2016.3 you can automatically convert `require` to `import`.

See the following [youtube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kScGj5C-Ekg#t=1m31s).

This is also described on the [JetBrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/11/intellij-idea-2016-3-ga-java-8-and-es6-debugger-and-ui-improvements-and-a-ton-more/):

> ECMAScript 6. IntelliJ IDEA now reports all var declarations and helps replace them with let or const declarations, depending on recognized value semantics. **For all require() calls, the IDE now provides a quick-fix that replaces them with import statements.** For function calls and prototype chains, the IDE provides a quick-fix that replaces them with class statements. Other improvements include better support for destructuring assignments, and default exports.

Comment: How to convert all `require` in project?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to convert 'require' to ES6 imports. if you miss this feature, please create a feature request in youtrack, youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB